# Error: Operator == not compatible with types address and bytes32

Tags: solidity, remix, addresses, error, data-types

How can I change the last line in the following code to make it work?

```
contract University { 
    address public owner; 
    address public student; 
    bytes32 fName; 
    bytes32 lName; 
    bytes32 Studies; 
    bytes32 private caCertificate; 
    bytes32 ipfs_hash;

    constructor() public { 
        owner = msg.sender; 
    } 

     modifier onlyOwner() { if (msg.sender == owner) _; } 
     modifier onlyOwnerOrStudent() { 
         if (msg.sender == owner || msg.sender == student) _; 

    .....
}
```

I get the error message:

> Operator == not compatible with types address and bytes32

Comment: Can you include the part of the code where these variables get initialized? It seems like they are of different types, which is causing the error...

Comment: contract University  address public owner address public student
 bytes32 fName
 bytes32 lName
 bytes32 Studies
 constructor() public {
 owner = msg.sender; }
 modifier onlyOwner()  {
        if (msg.sender == owner) _; }
    modifier onlyOwnerOrStudent() {
        if (msg.sender == owner || msg.sender == student) _;  }
    function setstudent () function getStudent ();
   event student(
        bytes32 fName,
        bytes32 lName,
        bytes32 Studies );
        function checkStudentExists() public constant returns (bool) {
        if (student == lName) return true;}

Comment: Code in comments is often unreadable due to formatting. (That code also seems to be mangled in other ways; it would not compile.) Please edit your question with the correct source code.

Comment: contract University {
    address public owner;
    address public student;
    bytes32 fName;
    bytes32 lName;
    bytes32 Studies;
    bytes32 private caCertificate;
    bytes32 ipfs_hash;
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    modifier onlyOwner()  {
        if (msg.sender == owner) _;
    }
    modifier onlyOwnerOrStudent() {
        if (msg.sender == owner || msg.sender == student) _;

Comment: function setstudent ();
    
    function getStudent ();
    
    event student(
        bytes32 fName,
        bytes32 lName,
        bytes32 Studies,
        bytes32 ipfs_hash
        );
        
    function checkStudentExists() public constant returns (bool) {
        if (student == lName) return true;
    }

Comment: you are comparing data types of `address` and `bytes32 for equality`. Since they are two data types operator is not allowed. you need make either student to `bytes32` or fName to `address` depending on your use-case

Comment: What does bytes32Equal do in this situation?                                                  
            for (i = 0; i < numRegData; i++) {
            if (bytes32Equal(getRegDataHash(i), _hash) == true) {
                _revokeDate = getDeletedRegDat(i);
                if (_revokeDate == 0) {
                    return (0, addrParent, _newHash);
                }    Can it be replaced with something else?

Comment: It's hard to answer a separate question like that, I think it's better to answer a new question and put your code formatted there to make it readable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are comparing data types of `address` and `bytes32` for equality. Since they are two data types operator is not allowed. you need make either `student` to `bytes32` or `fName` to `address` depending on your use-case.